# Unexpected mathematical output

Tags: python

I am trying to count my eggs in an exercise in Learning Python the Hard Way. The formula for counting the eggs is:

```
print (3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6)
```

and the suggested answer is `7`. 
I am getting `6.75` and have no idea why, I think I am putting it in correctly but I could be wrong. The way it is shown above is exactly how I have put it into the program.

Note: The book I am using uses the 2.6 version of Python where I am using the 3.1 version. This might be part of the confusion. Please help.

The URL for reference [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex3.html).

Comment: Better also use some 2.x version. They are not outdated as you think. [Python Wiki Python2 or Python3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Comment: @therealmarv While that's probably better when reading the book, Python3 still has some extremely nice additions and gets rid of exactly such design "mistakes" (defaulting to integer division in a dynamic language just has its problems), one could also see it as an additional learning experience. Also your link is a bit old already, Python3 support is getting better and better

Comment: @Voo Well. I'm not a big fan of Python3 because it breaks backward compability with Python2. There are a lot of good libraries and frameworks which do not work with Python3. Popular examples: Django or Google App Engine

Comment: @therealmarv Sure it's a pity that some extremely useful libraries aren't ported and I'm still using 2.7 (with import future) for several applications for that reason. It's getting better, but still not perfect I totally agree. But if I start a new project and know that good Python3 libraries exist for all I need I'd always prefer it against python2. The better unicode support alone (ie complaining loudly when I do something stupid) has stopped me from making intricate bugs.

Answer (score 12):

In python 2.x, the `/` operator did integer division. In python 3, the result of the `/` is a `float` regardless of the input types. Use the `//` operator to perform integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is non-backwards-compatible with Python 2.  Use the version of Python that your book is based on for least confusion.  As others have mentioned, Python 3 and Python 2 perform division differently, among other things.